# convention for storing procedures to send data to external application in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

What is the convention for sending data to external application in rails? I am sending data from one app to another.  Right now my form is submitted to a controller action which calls a model method to create an HTTP.post and return the response back to the controller.  I am wondering where should code like that be placed by convention? Somewhere in /lib or in a special non-active_record model?  The current way works, but it seems like there is a more appropriate place for the code.

Comment: do you need the response from the other app? seems like putting the requests in background would be better.

Comment: A response could be 'OK' or 'Fail' with error message.  Could you clarify what you mean by background? Like an background job queue?